# MSVC2015: __vcrt_UnhandledException could not be located

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2015

While updating a C++ project to VS2015 RC using Windows 7 I've hit the following error dialog while debugging:

> project_name.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> the procedure entry point __vcrt_UnhandledException could not be located in the dynamic link library VCRUNTIME140.ddl.

In the output window, (along with a typical list of missing PDBs) I get:

> Exception thrown at 0x775E1FB6 (ntdll.dll) in project_name.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
>
> The program '[9400] project_name.exe' has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.

My project depends on [SDL](http://libsdl.org), [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org) and [ODE](http://ode.org/).

I've tried a bunch of different things including changing the SubSystem from CONSOLE to WINDOWS, re-compiling SDL2 with various different options, replacing SDL2main.lib with an explicit `WinMain` function and changing compiler settings such as disabling exceptions.

I cannot find any mention of symbol `__vcrt_UnhandledException` online. What is necessary to make the code executable with VCRUNTIME140.dll?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this error is pretty obvious in hindsight but the feedback from the run-time was so unhelpful that I ended up trying a lot of different things before finding the answer.

It's likely that `UnhandledException` is simply the first symbol from the CRT to be required at program start-up. It is an indicator that a different version of the Visual C Run-Time DLL (from a VS2015 preview) is expected by something in the project (hence the `__vcrt_` in `__vcrt_UnhandledException`).

In this case, it's ODE that needs to be rebuild against VS2015 RC. More generally, make sure to rebuild *everything* when upgrading to a newer version of MSVC2015.

Comment: Hmm, that can't be it, VCRUNTIME140.dll is a VS2015 specific DLL.  Surely you are just paying the price for beta-testing a product that rapidly changes with each intermediary beta/rc update.

Comment: That makes more sense. I couldn't remember if the offending build of ODE was downloaded or build with the VS2015 preview. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes; this symbol existed in early preview builds of the Visual C++ 2015 runtime libraries.  It was removed in CTP6 or RC (I have forgotten which).  In general, we may make breaking changes to the libraries up to the release candidate (RC) build; we do not make any breaking changes after that.